# Limit of the sequence of $p$-norms

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, monotone-functions

Let $f : [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Show that the sequence
$$\left(\int_ 0^1 |f(x)|^n dx\right)^{1/n}$$
is convergent.

How can I show that this is a monotone sequence? ( I am thinking to apply monotone convergence theorem but was not able to go any further)

Comment: Try constant functions first. Then use that a general $f$ as given has a maximum and a minimum on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $|f|$ is continuous on a closed interval, $|f|$ achieves its maximum $M$ at some point $x_0$. Assume without loss of generality that $f\geq0$ and that $M=1$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and 
let $$E=\{x:\ f(x)>1-\varepsilon\}.$$
By continuity of $f$ we have that $E$ is open, so its measure is not zero.
Then
\begin{align}
\left(\int_0^1f(x)^n\,dx\right)^{1/n}
&\geq\left(\int_Ef(x)^n\,dx\right)^{1/n}\geq(1-\varepsilon)\,m(E)^{1/n}.
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
1\geq\limsup_n\left(\int_0^1f(x)^n\,dx\right)^{1/n}\geq\liminf_n\left(\int_0^1f(x)^n\,dx\right)^{1/n}
&\geq1-\varepsilon.
\end{align}
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the limit exists and is equal to $1$ (that is, to $M$ in the general case).

Comment: I still don't follow how you approached the problem. Can you emphasize more on what concept you used? And suggest a book or pdf where I can learn the same?

Comment: The idea is easy to understand if instead of considering $f$ on $[0,1]$ you do the two-point version: that is, show that $$\left(|a|^n+|b|^n\right)^{1/n}\to \max\{|a|,|b|\}.$$

Comment: (It's been a long time since I asked this question) Thankyou and in fact now I have a better understanding of what you wanted to convey, But I can't get my head around why define $E$, Can I do it directly i.e we know f is bounded hence M−ε<f(x)<=M and therefore to the last statement i.e $M-ε<a<sub>n</sub><=M$ by substituting M and M-ε in place of $f(x)$

Comment: I don't follow. The only function that satisfies $M-\varepsilon\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ is the constant function $f(x)=M$.

Comment: If we consider set A={ f(x) | x belongs to [0,1]} then M=Sup(A) and hence the inequality, there exist x such that M-e<f(x) <=M. But "this inequality doesn't happen for every x", is this what you were referring? And is this the reason why we can't substitute directly?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what $E$ is for.